# make build-deps throws an error

Tags: node

I've tried installing cargo on $HOME and /tmp to no avail. Can anyone help out?[image]

Comment: By the way, I'm following this guide: https://opentezos.com/deploy-a-node/installation

Answer (score 0):

Installation of cargo and rust dependencies is covered in the following section of the documentation: https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html#install-rust.

Comment: thanks. I retried all steps on a new Digital Ocean droplet but I still get the same error

<><> Error report <><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><><>
┌─ The following actions failed
│ λ build conf-rust 0.1
└─
╶─ No changes have been performed

The packages you requested declare the following system dependencies. Please make sure they are installed before retrying:
    cargo

I also followed the steps here to no avail: https://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html#install-rust

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is some issue related to the opam sandbox.

**From root:**

```
/root/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ls -a ..
```

> drwxr-xr-x root .
> drwxr-xr-x root ..
> drwxr-xr-x root tezos

**From a regular user:**

```
/home/user/.opam/opam-init/hooks/sandbox.sh build ls -a ..
```

> drwxr-xr-x user .
> drwxr-xr-x user ..
> drwxr-xr-x user .cargo
> drwxr-xr-x user .opam
> drwxr-xr-x user .rustup
> drwxr-xr-x user .zcash-params
> drwxr-xr-x user tezos
> ....

The above shows that the sandbox now handles the root directory differently and, because of that, it cannot find the cargo binaries located at `~/.cargo/bin/*`.

You are probably using `root`.

My suggestion is that you create a new user and try again.